# Compile time error - can't find symbol in import java.io.BufferedReader;

Tags: java, bufferedreader, codenameone

Using Java with NetBeans IDE I have a program that gives me no errors or warnings until I compile it, but which then tells me:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import java.io.BufferedReader;
  symbol:   class BufferedReader
  location: package java.io
1 error
```

(Full error on bottom)

To give a full example, I will use a template generated from a plugin I'm using, CODAPPS, where all I've done is add the line `import java.io.BufferedReader;` . The import is unused in the  example, but the error is the same as with my program:

**StateMachine.java**

```
/**
 * Your application code goes here
 */

package userclasses;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import generated.StateMachineBase;
import com.codename1.ui.*; 
import com.codename1.ui.events.*;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;

/**
 *
 * @author Your name here
 */
public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase {
    public StateMachine(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
        // do not modify, write code in initVars and initialize class members there,
        // the constructor might be invoked too late due to race conditions that might occur
    }

    /**
     * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of
     * the constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
     */
    protected void initVars(Resources res) {
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
Updating property file: C:\Users\hackr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CodenameOne Hello World\build\built-jar.properties
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\hackr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CodenameOne Hello World\build\tmp
C:\Users\hackr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CodenameOne Hello World\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import java.io.BufferedReader;
  symbol:   class BufferedReader
  location: package java.io
1 error
```

The command to compile the program, which is generated when i click the green "play" button in NetBeans is:

`ant -f "C:\\Users\\hackr\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CodenameOne Hello World" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run`

Comment: That is some strange error, given that this class is provided by the JDK... Can you show the full command used to compile?

Comment: @fge Yes, it's bizarre. I think this is what you're asking for, I'll add it to the question `ant -f "C:\\Users\\hackr\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CodenameOne Hello World" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run`

Comment: Can you import anything else from java.io? From java.*?

Comment: One has to go back to Java 1.0 to not have `java.io.BufferedReader`. As this also concerns generated sources, maybe a multi-project (generate/compile stages) might be something to look after. Maven would be clean. Ant can do when a bit careful.

Comment: @laune Yes, I think so. Without actually using it in the code I imported `import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;` and a few other things and I did not get an error

Comment: Check the version of ant that's being used (`ant -version`) and check your JAVA_HOME variable to be sure that it's using the correct JDK.

Comment: @ManDestra Good idea. It says the Ant version is 1.9.4 and Ant home is `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\extide\ant`. JDK is 1.8.

Comment: @JoopEggen I'm probably too new to Java to fully understand your comment regarding the generate/compile stages, but I will try to figure it out and update the question accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the CODEAPP Java documentation [on Codename One's CODAPPS site](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/index.html), everything is clear: You aren't developing or compiling against any full-blown Java JDK but to a restricted subset, that is enhanced with some stuff for mobile apps.

You cannot use `java.io.BufferedReader`. Use the Javadoc at the link to see what you may use.

If you think it is worth the trouble, you can plunder the JDK source - grepcode will find it for you if you haven't downloaded all the JDK sources. Or look at it, learn from it, and roll your own - you may not need all the features of that class.

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks for editing. I finally found the suitable tag (codenameone).

Comment: Great, thanks for solving this manual for me. I should've read the manual better; I just never suspected functionality could be removed from Java!

Comment: Notice that all streams in Codename One are buffered by default so the need of the buffering functionality in the JDK no longer exists. A lot of helper code for IO is accessible via the [Util](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html) class.